# Header propagation using .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, http-headers

I'm trying to propagate the HTTP header "x-request-id".

```
services.AddHeaderPropagation(o =>
    {
        // Propagate if the header exists
        o.Headers.Add("x-request-id");
    });

services.AddHttpClient<IDataProvider, UmsProvider>((sp, client) =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("testaddress");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    }).AddHeaderPropagation();
```

The above code does propagate the header, but the header name "x-request-id" changes to "X-Request-ID" in the downstream HTTP call.

Comment: Is your problem solved ? If you want to keep header "x-request-id" , you can create a custom DelegatingHandler to ensure the exact casing you require.